# display inline-flex in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

im using bootstrap, and angularjs to create a web app, and im trying to create a input-group, and im using `display: inline-flex` and it works great in Chrome but not in IE, here is what i have in my CSS and some screen shots.

```
.input-group {
    display: inline-flex !important;
    height: 31px;
}
```

[image: inline-flex chrome]
[image: inline-flex IE]

thanks in advance.

[Example in Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vc9YGOUv6fZsFoWr6h2S?p=preview)

edit: here is a plunker i created to recreate my question, if you open the plnkr in Chrome the input stack but if you open in IE is like nothing happen.

Comment: Witch version of IE are you targetting?

Comment: hello im targetting internet explorer 10

Comment: The question is not in fact answered in the alleged duplicate.  
Assuming this is for IE10, the answer David is after is `display: -ms-inline-flexbox;`

Comment: use this alternative 

 display: -webkit-inline-flex;
display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
display: inline-flex;