# Display: inline-flex property not working in IE-10

Tags: css, flexbox

My wrapper div has one class which has 
display: inline-flex as the property.

It works smooth with chrome and firefox. But not with IE. I am using version 10.
How can i write it for IE?

Comment: this could be of some help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514534/display-inline-flex-in-internet-explorer

Comment: You can't do this easily, since IE10 does not support it. The simplest solution is to remove IE10 from your list of supported browsers, as most other companies (including MS itself) have done.

Comment: What i did for the same was: make parent div to be displayed as block and all the child elements as inline-block. It worked for me.